# Given $K$ points in the $N$-simplex, when is there a unique $M$-polytope that contains the $K$ points?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, convex-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, convex-hulls

> Given $K$ points in the $N$-simplex, when is there a unique $M$-polytope that contains the $K$ points?

For example, in the below image $K=13, N= 2, M=3$. Clearly the polytope (the inner triangle) can be moved around while still containing those points, so it is nonunique.

[image]

**Here are some simple cases I can think of:**

- $N=K=M$, and the points are the vertices of the simplex.
- $K,N>M$, and $M$ of the points are on the faces of the simplex.

What is a general criterion?

**Related question:** when does no such polytope exist? This can happen if $N,K>M$ and there are more than $K$ distinct points on the faces of the simplex. Is this the only case?

Comment: This question is unclear (to me). If you [edit] it to show us pictures in the plane we may be able to help. There the simplex is an equilateral triangle. Provide some examples with different numbers and positions of points and tell us in those cases whether there are no polytopes of the kind you seek, or just one, or more than one. (Do not try to clarify in a comment.)

Comment: @EthanBolker sure, edited.

Comment: That's a little clearer but not enough so, for me. What does "moved around" mean? Show us some other polytopes that work. Add more pictures with unique and impossible cases. The "topic" labels in your picture suggest that barycentric coordinates may help. Perhaps tell us the problem that led to this question.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sure, I'll check out barycentric coordinates, thanks. Unfortunately I don't have any method to draw on the image but by nonunique polytope t mean there can be slight perturbations in the vertices of the polytope that would keep the points inside.This is my motivating question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086812/jellybean-mixing-problem

Comment: The $K$ points are always included in their convex hull.

Comment: @Tobsn yes! The $M$-polytope must contain that convex hull, and I am wondering under what conditions the two are exactly equal.